# UI artifacts in kubuntu 17.04

Tags: nvidia

I have dell latitude 3450, running kubuntu 17.04. I am facing UI artifacts (PFA). It follows the mouse. If I switch window, the previous window rectangle persists on the new window (see highlighted in snapshot). Any ideas how to resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, what resolved above issue is system settings->display and monitor->compositor->rendering backend = opengl 3.1/2.0.

try different options. logout->relogin or reboot

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. If I logout/login, the problem resolves. Idem on restart X Server before the first login.
Intel driver work correctly.

Comment: so far, no progress still. I do daily apt-get update/upgrade. hoping to land a patch, but no results unfortunately.